# Illuminate returns results in JSON - why?

Tags: illuminate-container

I'm using Illuminate to access my database

```
<body> 
 <?php
    $edges = Edge::all();

    foreach ($edges as $key => $value) {
    print $value;
    }
 ?>
</body>
```

browser returns:

```
{"childID":"A","parentID":"C","updated_at":null,"created_at":null}{"childID":"B","parentID":"E","updated_at":null,"created_at":null}{"childID":"C","parentID":"D","updated_at":null,"created_at":null}{"childID":"C","parentID":"F","updated_at":null,"created_at":null}{"childID":"Y","parentID":"Z","updated_at":"2014-08-07 10:26:54","created_at":"2014-08-07 10:26:54"}
```

What's odd or unexpected for me at least is that my results are returned in JSON. If you could
shine some light on this, i.e. why this might be, or the reason is...I'd be grateful.

If I dump the results in the browser with:

```
<?php
 print '<pre>';print_r($edges);
?>
```

produces:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object
(
 [items:protected] => Array
    (
        [0] => Edge Object
            (
                [connection:protected] => 
                [table:protected] => 
                [primaryKey:protected] => id
                [perPage:protected] => 15
                [incrementing] => 1
                [timestamps] => 1
                [attributes:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [childID] => A
                        [parentID] => C
                        [updated_at] => 
                        [created_at] => 
                    )

                [original:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [childID] => A
                        [parentID] => C
                        [updated_at] => 
                        [created_at] => 
                    )

                [relations:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [hidden:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [visible:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [appends:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [fillable:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [guarded:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => *
                    )

                [dates:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [touches:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [observables:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [with:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [morphClass:protected] => 
                [exists] => 1
            )

        [1] => Edge Object
            (...)

 ...
)
```

In terms of the front-end results - I'm really only interested in the:

```
[childID] => A
[parentID] => C
[updated_at] => 
[created_at] =>
```

part of the object; only NOT in JSON; in plain text.